# How to calculate Default Raster cell size in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

From this topic i want to know why we have to divide by 250? what is 250 means? where is form?

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/environments/cell-size.htm

> The default cell size when a feature dataset is used as input to a
> tool is the width or height (whichever is shorter) of the extent of
> the feature dataset, **divided by 250.**

Comment: ArcGIS is providing a default value so it has to determine it somehow. I don't know why they picked 250 pixels. However, you don't have to use the default, you can specify your own cell size and determine it however you like.

Comment: Might I also recommend looking at the snap raster environment, using cell size and snap raster set to an existing raster avoids lots of problems when overlaying rasters as the cell size is the same and aligns perfectly avoiding the need for resampling which slows down processing and introduces slight value changes. Setting these overrides the default which is just an arbitrary number decided by a developer long ago who may not have ever used the tools for GIS work.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer.